# Connect to Hbase on Cloudera VM using the Java Client API :

Tags: java, sockets, hbase

I am using the following JAVA code to establish the connection :

```
 Configuration hConfig = null;
        hConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        hConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", **zookepperQuorum**);
        hConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", **zookepperClientPort**);
 HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(hConfig);
```

This is my ipConfig from CmdLine on windows :

**Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:**

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a03b:5ec2:cc82:f952%12

**IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.108.0.87**

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.108.0.1

**Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:**

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ecfb:969e:aa2e:1195%52

**IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1**

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

This is my **Hosts file** in the cloudera VM :

**127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost**

I tried out different things to connect to Hbase according to suggestions on the net, but those did not work for me.

**I am getting the following error :**

**13/11/11 16:13:03 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing 
socket connection and attempting reconnect**

**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information**

at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)

at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)

at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)

```
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

13/11/11 16:13:03 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception:

org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for

/hbase/hbaseid

13/11/11 16:13:03 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 4000ms before retry #2...

13/11/11 16:13:04 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server

localhost.localdomain/192.168.56.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

**13/11/11 16:13:05 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing 
socket connection and attempting reconnect**

**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information**

```
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)

at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)

at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)

at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

**13/11/11 16:13:06 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/192.168.56.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)**

It would be great if anyone can list steps which will help me in setting up the remote connection.

Comment: Hi Mayuresh, I am also facing the similar issue, did you find any solution to it?

Comment: Not yet. I am trying to see if anyone on the cloudera google grps has the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but I hope others might benefit from it.

When getting the error "Session 0x0 for server null" one of the likely issues is that your HBase-code doesn't know where to connect. Best way to solve this is to load your hbase-site.xml config-file.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.addResource(new Path("/XXXX/hbase/hbase-0.98.9/conf/hbase-site.xml"));
```